# Jquery Datepicker not worked on clone function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been work with jquery datepicker but somehow idk when i clone it's dont work maybe can someone help me fix this error

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: -7,
            maxDate: "+1M +10D"

        });
    });
    $('.add-more-btn').click(function() {

        // Create clone of <div class='input-form'>
        var newel = $('.form-main:last').clone().val("");

        // Add after last <div class='input-form'>
        $(newel).insertAfter(".form-main:last").classRemove('.hasDatepicker');
    });

    $(".btn-reset-form").click(function() {
        $('.form-main:last').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: do you need clone or need just want to add new date picker?

Comment: i need it for add new form and i want the value is blank not copy from the original form